# Why does my code display "player not found"?

Tags: javascript

So I have this command that's supposed to display a player's stats if it's found and says player not found otherwise. After I search a player and go to the previous screen, I get "player not found". I thought it was because my loop continues running after the player is found and my boolean becomes false, so I added a break statement. Won't work

```
function Search(Table, Stat1, Stat2, Stat3, Stat4, Stat5) {
    onEvent("Search2.btn", "click", function() {
        readRecords(Table, {}, function(records) {
            var SearchPlayer = getText("text_input1");
            var found = false;
            for (var i = 0; i < records.length; i++) {
                if ((records[i]).Player == SearchPlayer) {
                    setScreen("DisplaySearch");
                    setText("label3", records[i].Player + " Stats" + "\n" + records[i][Stat1] + " " + Stat1 + "\n" + records[i][Stat2] + " " + Stat2 + "\n" + records[i][Stat3] + " " + Stat3 + "\n" + records[i][Stat4] + " " + Stat4 + "\n" + records[i][Stat5] + " " + Stat5 + "\n");
                    setText("text_input1", "");
                    setText("label5", "");
                    found = true;
                    break;
                } else if ((found == false)) {
                    setText("label5", "Player Not Found");
                }
            }
        });
    });
```

Comment: We don't know what is in `records` or `Search`; if you do, please share.

Comment: Search is the name of my function that I called later, didn't display that. Record is the database where all my player names and stats are stored

Comment: `Search` is the variable holding the value you get by calling `getText("text_input1")`.

Comment: Well it's both, didn't notice

Comment: I'll change the name for clarity

Comment: Still don't know what is in `records`.